# Having trouble using localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I just wanted it to greet the user when he/she comes back again and never greet the user when it's his/her first time visiting the page. Ik that the data from the localStorage could only be removed if the user manually deletes it.

Here's my code:

```
function hEY() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    var yourName = document.getElementById("customer").value;
    var stored = localStorage.getItem("uname");
    if (stored != yourName) {
      localStorage.setItem("uname", yourName);
    }

    if (stored == yourName) {
      alert("Welcome back " + yourName + "!");
    } else {
      alert("You are not " + yourName + "!");
    }

  } else {
    alert("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage");
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: You should check whether `stored` is `null` to tell if this is their first time.

Answer (score 1):

The first time they go to the site, `stored` will be `null`. Check for that and don't display the greeting.

```js
function hEY() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    var yourName = document.getElementById("customer").value;
    var stored = localStorage.getItem("uname");
    let firstTime = stored == null;
    if (stored != yourName) {
      localStorage.setItem("uname", yourName);
    }
    if (!firstTime) {
      if (stored == yourName) {
        alert("Welcome back " + yourName + "!");
      } else {
        alert("You are not " + yourName + "!");
      }
    }

  } else {
    alert("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage");
  }
}
```